# Apache/Nginx configuration issue after uninstalling laravel/valet and homestead on macOS Sierra

Tags: apache, laravel, nginx, macos-sierra, laravel-valet

After uninstalling laravel/valet and Homestead on macOS Sierra, I switched back to Apache (rather than NGINX), tried to restart it using `sudo apachectl -k restart`, and it outputs this error:

```
httpd not running, trying to start
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

**Additional Info** - using Homebrew 1.3.1 with OS Sierra 10.12.6. Also used a similar local environment to the one found here:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

**Disclaimer:** *I almost never use NGINX but I'm assuming it, or something else involved in the laravel/valet setup is preventing Apache from binding to the right port.*

**How do I fix this error and reconfigure Apache to work with Homebrew again, instead of NGINX?**

No output from `lsof -i | grep LISTEN | grep ":80"` but the output of `sudo lsof -i :80` below:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   12146 root    4u  IPv6 0x3f591ee6220c2a09      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   12148 _www    4u  IPv6 0x3f591ee6220c2a09      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   37113 _www    4u  IPv6 0x3f591ee6220c2a09      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   37114 _www    4u  IPv6 0x3f591ee6220c2a09      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   37115 _www    4u  IPv6 0x3f591ee6220c2a09      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   38654 _www    4u  IPv6 0x3f591ee6220c2a09      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if nginx is running

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

If it is running then check if it is running using brew

```
brew services list
```

If that shows nginx started then you use below command to stop it

```
brew services stop nginx
```

If it is not listed as started or not listed as a service then try to manually kill nginx

```
pkill nginx
```

Now to try to restart apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Outputs:                                                                                     
samuelmccray     42065   0.0  0.0  2432804   1956 s000  S+    1:57AM   0:00.00 grep nginx
Name    Status  User Plist
dnsmasq stopped
httpd24 started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist
Error: Service `nginx` is not started.                                                         
(then the same error as before after here)

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -i | grep LISTEN | grep ":80"` This will tell you which program is listening to port 80. Add the results to your question and don't comment for reply

Comment: There was no output from that exact CLI command but I added more info above in the question

Comment: Do a `pkill httpd` then

Comment: awesome, that seems to have worked! I had to reinstall and reconfigure PHP but it seems to be working now, thanks!